# "errorMessage": "module initialization error"

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

Using Python, I followed and when it came to `Test` it, the following error popped up:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "module initialization error"
}
```

What could I have done wrong?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
from datetime import datetime
from urllib2 import urlopen

SITE = os.environ['site']  # URL of the site to check, stored in the site environment variable, e.g. https://aws.amazon.com
EXPECTED = os.environ['expected']  # String expected to be on the page, stored in the expected environment variable, e.g. Amazon


def validate(res):
    '''Return False to trigger the canary

    Currently this simply checks whether the EXPECTED string is present.
    However, you could modify this to perform any number of arbitrary
    checks on the contents of SITE.
    '''
    return EXPECTED in res


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('Checking {} at {}...'.format(SITE, event['time']))
    try:
        if not validate(urlopen(SITE).read()):
            raise Exception('Validation failed')
    except:
        print('Check failed!')
        raise
    else:
        print('Check passed!')
        return event['time']
    finally:
        print('Check complete at {}'.format(str(datetime.now())))
```

Comment: show your code.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz The code is from the `lambda-canary` blueprint they provide. Didn't change anything. Just followed through the tutorial exactly. Regardless, copied and pasted it to the original post.

Comment: What is the entry point you mentioned in your  lambda configurations?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz I don't ever recall setting up an entry point during the tutorial process. Is there another way to check it?

Comment: If you go to lambda configuration settings tab, you will see an option `Handler` , can you tell me what is value of that field

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Actually looked at the log output and it showed: `module initialization error: 'site'`. Recall seeing two environment variables during set up, `site` and `expected`, but deleted them since it didn't let me proceed unless I provided values for them. Did not know what the values were, and the tutorial did not mention them, so deleted them, and proceeded.

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz Yes, the `Handler` has: `lambda_function.lambda_handler`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need any environment variables. Just keep it simple

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
from datetime import datetime
from urllib2 import urlopen


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    url = 'https://www.google.com' # change it with your own
    print('Checking {} at {}...'.format(url, datetime.utcnow()))
    html = urlopen(url).read()
    # do some processing
    return html
```

Here is another simple example.

```
from __future__ import print_function


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    first = event.get('first', 0)
    second = event.get('second', 0)
    sum = first + second
    return sum
```

Here is a sample event which will be used to invoke this lambda. you can configure event from Lambda web interface. (or google it)

```
{
  "first": 10,
  "second": 23
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your response! But do you mind explaining what you are doing for learning purposes? And where do I get the `URL`? And when would I need the environment variables?

Comment: In this lambda function, we are retrieving an html page. but you lambda can do anything. e.g. you can add two numbers. let me change the code

Comment: Ah got it! Thought that was the solution to the problem rather than an example. But in the examples provided, what really is the solution to the problem I encountered? Also, would like to use `Scheduled Event` in the `Sample event` list as tutorial suggests.

Comment: my question is what do you want to achieve? tell me your use case?

Comment: Definitely, wondering what's resolving the issue. Is it because I didn't provide `SITE = os.environ['site'] `, yet trying to access it?

Comment: Also got a new error with the sum example provided: `{
  "stackTrace": [
    [
      "/var/task/lambda_function.py",
      9,
      "lambda_handler",
      "return {statusCode: 200, body: {'answer': sum}}"
    ]
  ],
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "errorMessage": "global name 'statusCode' is not defined"
}`

Comment: Exactly. environment variables are set while creating lambda but in my opinion, passing site url through environment variable is not a good idea unless you have different environments like dev, staging, production etc. if you that value from environment variables, set that first

Comment: I missed `quotes` , change `statusCode` to `"statusCode"`

Comment: And I think you know what is an upvote and selected answer :P XD

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143130/discussion-between-ly-maneug-and-zohaib-ijaz).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I missed adding the `logging_config.ini` to the lambda function.

I guess you would face similar error when the lambda function doesn't find the referenced file or package.

Thanks to the new cloud9 IDE integration, I was able to create one on the fly.